# Unexpected token > jquery ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm making an ajax call to a webmethod and I'm getting the error "unexpected Token >"  I'm not sure why I'm getting this.. Any ideas?

```
function addToQueue(me) {

    if (validateTimeFrame()) {
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "GenerateReportModal.aspx/AddToPrintQueue?id=" + $('#patientNum').val(),
            data: {buttonID: me.id},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                alert(data);
                $('#GenerateReportModal').dialog('close');
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(errorThrown + ' ' + textStatus);
                console.log(jqXHR);
                $('#GenerateReportModal').dialog('close');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

<----------------------------------------------->

```
[WebMethod]
public string AddToPrintQueue(string buttonID)
{
    try
    {
        var deIdentify = 0;
        var adminUserNum = Int32.Parse(Session["AdminUserNum"].ToString());

        if ((Session["AdminUserNum"].ToString() == "6460" || Session["AdminUserNum"].ToString() == "6537" || Session["AdminUserNum"].ToString() == "7885") && (Session["ClinicalDataAdmin"].ToString() == "1" || Session["AccountAdmin"].ToString() == "1" || Session["SystemAdmin"].ToString() == "1"))
            deIdentify = (cbDeIdentify.Checked == true) ? 1 : 0;
        else
            deIdentify = 0;

        switch (buttonID)
        {
            case "FollowUpAddtoQueue":
                FollowUpAddToQueueClass(deIdentify);
                break;
            case "WearTimeAddToQueue":
                WearTimeAddToQueueClass(deIdentify);
                break;
            case "TrendsAddToQueue":
                TrendsAddToQueueClass(deIdentify);
                break;
            case "EndOfUseAddToQueue":
                EndofUseAddToQueueClass(deIdentify);
                break;
        }
     }
     catch
     {
        return "There was an issue, we appologize for the inconvenience";
     }

     return "Added to print queue";
 }
```

<---------------------------------------------------->

```
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClientClick="return addToQueue(this); return false;" CssClass="button" ID="EndOfUseAddToQueue" Width="150" Text="<%$ Resources:PatientDetail, btnModAddtoQueue %>" />
```

Comment: Are you getting `data` into `alert(data)`??

Comment: It's because the browser is not expecting the end of your return from the webmethod. Something is syntactically wrong with your response.

Comment: @Dhaval - It's not going into success, so I'm not sure. it's returning the error function.

Comment: @Michael - The returned response from the web method? Should it be something other than a string?

Comment: I needed to make the web method static in order for it to work. Unfortunate because I could no longer reference the values of all the input objects on the aspx page directly by adding "runat=server".  I had to pass them all through the web method's arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by making the webmethod static...

```
[WebMethod]
public static string AddToPrintQueue(string buttonID)
{  
...
}
```

Bit of a bummer because I could no longer reference the input objects directly from the aspx page.  All the values needed to be passed through the ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

You're returning a string from your Webmethod, but you've told jQuery to expect JSON.

```
$.ajax({
    //...
    dataType: "json",
    //...
});
```

Change that to text (or take it out completely) and see if that solves your problem. Refer to the `dataType` property of the [jQuery AJAX documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

`dataType: "json"`, asks you to return `json` type from `webmethod`!! So you need to decorate your `webmethod` with below line

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] //Add this
public string AddToPrintQueue(string buttonID)
{
     try
     {
           //Your other code
     }
     catch
     {
          return "There was an issue, we appologize for the inconvenience";
     }

     return "Added to print queue";
}
```

In addition to this try specifying `contentType` in your `ajax` call as below:

```
$.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "GenerateReportModal.aspx/AddToPrintQueue?id=" + $('#patientNum').val(),
      data: {buttonID: me.id},
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", //Add this line too
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
              alert(data);
              $('#GenerateReportModal').dialog('close');
      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              console.log(errorThrown + ' ' + textStatus);
              console.log(jqXHR);
              $('#GenerateReportModal').dialog('close');
      }
});
```

Comment: Assuming, of course, that you want the data on the client as JSON, rather than a string. If you want a string instead (as it looks from your webmethod) then just take the dataType property out of your `$.ajax()` call, as I described.

Answer (score 0):

I think WebMethod doesn't accept query string parameter. You should try to call webmethod by only post method.

Answer (score 0):

One quickie might be related to the question itself or might just be an tip on the road.

This line: `data: {buttonID: me.id}` makes your webmethod believe that you are sending them an object named buttonID and not as a string as stated in your C# method.

You should change to `data: {'buttonID': me.id}` if you want it to be seen as a string and not an object.